# GWT - Not able to input text into TextArea

Tags: gwt, textarea

I have a strange problem to solve.
I have a GWT Textarea where it is not possible to input text to it, however, I am able to setText automatically.

I already tried to

```
textBox.setEnabled(true);
textBox.setFocus(true);
textBox.setReadOnly(false);
```

but it has not changed anything.
When going through the css file, everything seems to me ok.

Here is the "whole" source code:

```
private Input(AbsolutePanel canvas) {

    textBox = new MouseEventTextBox();
    textBox.setStylePrimaryName(PRIMARY_STYLE);
    textBox.addKeyUpHandler(this);
    textBox.addKeyDownHandler(this);
    textBox.addFocusHandler(this);
    textBox.addBlurHandler(this);
    textBox.setEnabled(true);
    textBox.setFocus(true);
    textBox.setReadOnly(false);
    textBox.setText("Just an apple"); // Works, text is set but not editable
    canvas.add(textBox, -1000, -1000);
}

private class MouseEventTextBox extends TextArea{
    public MouseEventTextBox() {
        super();
        sinkEvents(Event.MOUSEEVENTS);
    }

    public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
        // Call the superclass' implementation first.
        super.onBrowserEvent(event);

        if ((DOM.eventGetButton(event) == Event.BUTTON_LEFT) && (DOM.eventGetType(event) == Event.ONMOUSEUP)) {
            this.setReadOnly(false);
            DOM.eventCancelBubble(event, true);
        }
    }
}
```

CSS

```
border-width: 0px;
background-color: #fffde5;
padding-top: 2px;
padding-left: 3px;
padding-right: 3px;
padding-bottom: 1px;
z-index: 50;
overflow: hidden;
```

Maybe, someone could give me a hint or know what is going wrong here?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The suspicious part of your code is:

```
textBox.addKeyUpHandler(this);
textBox.addKeyDownHandler(this);
textBox.addFocusHandler(this);
textBox.addBlurHandler(this);
```

That means, that `this` implements `KeyUpHandler`, `KeyDownHandler`, `FocusHandler` and `BlurHandler`. Unfortunately, you did not show us methods that handles those events.

I bet, that there is something wrong in your `onKeyDown` method. I was able to achieve the same behavior when I blocked the `KeyDownEvent` event (`stopPropagation`, `preventDefault`).

Check your browser console for errors. If none, comment out `textBox.addKeyDownHandler(this);` line.

Comment: Sorry, for answering so late. Here is my onKeyDown method. As I can see it is only handling the KEY_* Codes: public void onKeyDown(KeyDownEvent event) {

        if (menuOptions == null) {
            switch (event.getNativeKeyCode()) {
            case KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER:
            case KeyCodes.KEY_UP:
            case KeyCodes.KEY_DOWN:
            case KeyCodes.KEY_TAB:
                hide(true);
                break;
            default:
                DOM.eventCancelBubble(DOM.eventGetCurrentEvent(), true);
                break;
            }
        } 
    }

Comment: Please, try to comment out `textBox.add***Handler(this);` lines and see if `TextBox` works afterwards. Also check the browser's console for possible errors. Which GWT version do you use?

Comment: Hi Adam, thank you very much. No, it seems as if I am able to input text into the textbox. Well, I would really like to know why it works now?